# Got empty shared queue from multiprocessing processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I am trying to make an API validation from a given list of IP addresses using multiprocessing. All the processes contain the valid IPs will be stored in a shared queue. However, when I try to print the queue after the processes in the multiprocessing were executed, the final queue was empty. Could somebody show me how would I able to fix the code?

```
def validate(ip_address, results):
  try:
    response = requests.get('....API_URL....'))
    if response.status_code is 200:
        """ store in queue if valid """
        results.put(multiprocessing.current_process())

  except ConnectionError:
    pass

def main():
  """ ip_list is given """
  results = multiprocessing.Queue()

  processes = []
  for ip in ip_list:
      process = multiprocessing.Process(target = validate, args=(ip,results))
      processes.append(process)

  for p in processes:
      p.start()

  for p in processes:
      p.join()

  while results.empty() is False:
      result = results.get()
      final_list.append(result)

  print(final_list) ### EMPTY queue

main()
```

EDIT1: I tried to replace `results.put(multiprocessing.current_process())` with something random such as `results.put("randomTEXT")` but final_list still prints empty. Also, could someone please suggest me a way to store the identity/name/id of the process that successfully requests the API?

Comment: In `validate` did you try to replace the conditional statement and suite with a `put('somestring')` statement? did it work? Did you try to `put` something in the  `except` suite? - were there exceptions?

Comment: `multiprocessing.current_process()` returns an instance of `multiprocessing.context.Process`. This kind of object can not be passed through a `mp.Queue` because "Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons". You can see this error message by enabling logging: `import logging`, `logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So I tried to replace `results.put(multiprocessing.current_process())` with `results.put("randomTEXT")` but final_list still prints empty. Also, could you suggest me a way to store the identity/name/id of the process that successfully request the API? Many thanks!

Comment: @curiousP: You could put the string `mp.current_process().name` in the queue.

Comment: @curiousP: Building on wwii's idea, perhaps use `results.put((multiprocessing.current_process().name, response.status_code))` **outside** of the `if-statement` so you can see what `response.status_code`s you are getting.

Comment: @curiousP: When comparing numbers, [use `==`, not `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/190597). In your case, that means you should be using `if response.status_code == 200`.

Comment: `current_process().name` works nicely! Thank you very much!